# How can I validate an undefined index?

Tags: php, arrays, validation, undefined, isset

This is my code:

```
$fields = $bool === true ? $data[$value->uuid] : $data[$value->getUuid()];
```

in case "$value->uuid" oder "$value->uuid" is not an index of `$data`, I get an error message:

> Notice: Undefined index: 123

So I tried to make a validaton:

```
$fields = "";

      if(isset($data[$value->uuid])) {
        $fields = $data[$value->uuid];
      }
      if(isset($data[$value->getUuid()])) {
        $fields = $data[$value->getUuid()];
      }
```

But still I get the same error message.

Comment: Does this work?
`if(bool) { $fields = $data[$value->uuid] ?? $data[$value->getUuid()]; }`

Comment: You need else if(isset($data[$value->uuid])) {
        $fields = $data[$value->uuid];
      }else { echo "error! Id is empty "; }

Comment: `var_dump()` both `$data` and `$value` in your post.

Comment: @mark_b This gives the error `syntax error, unexpected '(bool)' (bool) (T_BOOL_CAST), expecting '('`

Comment: Sorry, typo! I missed off the $ at the beginning of the variable

Comment: @mark_b Now I get the error `Attempted to call an undefined method named "getUuid" of class "stdClass".`

Comment: @Dilek This seems to work

Comment: @fala can you show your array please in question

Comment: What is the purpose of $bool here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need also check if `$value` has properties:

```
if(isset($value->uuid) && isset($data[$value->uuid])) {
    $fields = $data[$value->uuid];
}

if(isset($value->getUuid()) && isset($data[$value->getUuid()])) {
    $fields = $data[$value->getUuid()];
}
```

First `isset()` checks property, second - index from `$data` array.
[Example](https://3v4l.org/odbMF)

**EDIT**

Your condition would looks like:

```
//$fields = $bool === true ? $data[$value->uuid] : $data[$value->getUuid()];

$uuid = '';
$uuid_fn = '';

if(isset($value->uuid) && isset($data[$value->uuid])) {
    $uuid = $data[$value->uuid];
}

if(isset($value->getUuid()) && isset($data[$value->getUuid()])) {
    $uuid_fn = $data[$value->getUuid()];
}

$fields = $bool === true ? $uuid : $uuid_fn;
```

Comment: I get the error `Compile Error: Cannot use isset() on the result of an expression (you can use "null !== expression" instead)`

Comment: @fala, it's cause of `$value->getUuid()`, what does it returns? You can follow the suggestion btw.

Comment: well depending on the $bool, if this is TRUE then I need $value->uuid, else I need $value->getUuid and in some cases neather $value->uuid nor $value->getUuid exists in data

Comment: @fala, I'm wondering how you will retrieve any data like `$data[true]`...